# PHP Agenda with mysql echoing records in a table

Tags: php, mysql

Good afternoon,

I am running into a problem witch i have no idea how to fix.

I am making a agenda thing with php and mysql but i think my approach is wrong. it works fine now if have 1 appointment on a day but if a have 2 it is broken.

My code:

```
        include('../dbc.php');

        $dag = $_GET['dag'];
        $maand = $_GET['maand'];
        $jaar = $_GET['jaar'];

        $datum = $jaar."-".$maand."-".$dag;


        $datavergader = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($dbc,"SELECT * FROM `tbl_reservatie` WHERE op = '".$datum."' AND ruimte = 'vergader';"));
```

Here i am making a table with every hour and half our and changing the class of  to change color if i have an appointment.

```
<table cellspacing="0" style="width:100%">
                  <tr>
                    <th>8:00</th>
                    <td <?php if($datavergader['van'] == "800"){echo 'class="bezet"';}else{ echo "class='beschikbaar'";} ?> ></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th>8:30</th>
                    <td <?php if(($datavergader['van'] <= "830") && ($datavergader['tot'] >= "830" )){echo 'class="bezet"';}else{ echo "class='beschikbaar'";} ?> ></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th>9:00</th>
                    <td <?php if(($datavergader['van'] <= "900") && ($datavergader['tot'] >= "900" )){echo 'class="bezet"';}else{ echo "class='beschikbaar'";} ?> ></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th>9:30</th>
                    <td <?php if(($datavergader['van'] <= "930") && ($datavergader['tot'] >= "930" )){echo 'class="bezet"';}else{ echo "class='beschikbaar'";} ?> ></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th>10:00</th>
                    <td <?php if(($datavergader['van'] <= "1000") && ($datavergader['tot'] >= "1000" )){echo 'class="bezet"';}else{ echo "class='beschikbaar'";} ?> ></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th>10:30</th>
                    <td <?php if(($datavergader['van'] <= "1030") && ($datavergader['tot'] >= "1030" )){echo 'class="bezet"';}else{ echo "class='beschikbaar'";} ?> ></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th>11:30</th>
                    <td <?php if(($datavergader['van'] <= "1130") && ($datavergader['tot'] >= "1130" )){echo 'class="bezet"';}else{ echo "class='beschikbaar'";} ?> ></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th>12:00</th>
                    <td <?php if(($datavergader['van'] <= "1200") && ($datavergader['tot'] >= "1200" )){echo 'class="bezet"';}else{ echo "class='beschikbaar'";} ?> ></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th>12:30</th>
                    <td <?php if(($datavergader['van'] <= "1230") && ($datavergader['tot'] >= "1230" )){echo 'class="bezet"';}else{ echo "class='beschikbaar'";} ?> ></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th>13:00</th>
                    <td <?php if(($datavergader['van'] <= "1300") && ($datavergader['tot'] >= "1300" )){echo 'class="bezet"';}else{ echo "class='beschikbaar'";} ?> ></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th>13:30</th>
                    <td <?php if(($datavergader['van'] <= "1330") && ($datavergader['tot'] >= "1330" )){echo 'class="bezet"';}else{ echo "class='beschikbaar'";} ?> ></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th>14:00</th>
                    <td <?php if(($datavergader['van'] <= "1400") && ($datavergader['tot'] >= "1400" )){echo 'class="bezet"';}else{ echo "class='beschikbaar'";} ?> ></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th>14:30</th>
                    <td <?php if(($datavergader['van'] <= "1430") && ($datavergader['tot'] >= "1430" )){echo 'class="bezet"';}else{ echo "class='beschikbaar'";} ?> ></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th>15:00</th>
                    <td <?php if(($datavergader['van'] <= "1500") && ($datavergader['tot'] >= "1500" )){echo 'class="bezet"';}else{ echo "class='beschikbaar'";} ?> ></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th>15:30</th>
                    <td <?php if(($datavergader['van'] <= "1530") && ($datavergader['tot'] >= "1530" )){echo 'class="bezet"';}else{ echo "class='beschikbaar'";} ?> ></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th>16:00</th>
                    <td <?php if(($datavergader['van'] <= "1600") && ($datavergader['tot'] >= "1600" )){echo 'class="bezet"';}else{ echo "class='beschikbaar'";} ?> ></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th>16:30</th>
                    <td <?php if(($datavergader['van'] <= "1630") && ($datavergader['tot'] >= "1630" )){echo 'class="bezet"';}else{ echo "class='beschikbaar'";} ?> ></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th>17:00</th>
                    <td <?php if(($datavergader['van'] <= "1700") && ($datavergader['tot'] >= "1700" )){echo 'class="bezet"';}else{ echo "class='beschikbaar'";} ?> ></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th>17:30</th>
                    <td <?php if(($datavergader['van'] <= "1730") && ($datavergader['tot'] >= "1730" )){echo 'class="bezet"';}else{ echo "class='beschikbaar'";} ?> ></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th>18:00</th>
                    <td <?php if(($datavergader['van'] <= "1800") && ($datavergader['tot'] >= "1800" )){echo 'class="bezet"';}else{ echo "class='beschikbaar'";} ?> ></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th>18:30</th>
                    <td <?php if(($datavergader['van'] <= "1830") && ($datavergader['tot'] >= "1830" )){echo 'class="bezet"';}else{ echo "class='beschikbaar'";} ?> ></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th>19:00</th>
                    <td <?php if(($datavergader['van'] <= "1900") && ($datavergader['tot'] >= "1900" )){echo 'class="bezet"';}else{ echo "class='beschikbaar'";} ?> ></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th>19:30</th>
                    <td <?php if(($datavergader['van'] <= "1930") && ($datavergader['tot'] >= "1930" )){echo 'class="bezet"';}else{ echo "class='beschikbaar'";} ?> ></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th>20:00</th>
                    <td <?php if(($datavergader['van'] <= "2000") && ($datavergader['tot'] >= "2000" )){echo 'class="bezet"';}else{ echo "class='beschikbaar'";} ?> ></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th>20:30</th>
                    <td <?php if(($datavergader['van'] <= "2030") && ($datavergader['tot'] >= "2030" )){echo 'class="bezet"';}else{ echo "class='beschikbaar'";} ?> ></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th>21:00</th>
                    <td <?php if(($datavergader['van'] <= "2100") && ($datavergader['tot'] >= "2100" )){echo 'class="bezet"';}else{ echo "class='beschikbaar'";} ?> ></td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
```

I know why its not echoing other appointments correctly because it can store only one record in the datavergader. but how could i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

try with `while()`

```
while ($datavergader = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($dbc,"SELECT * FROM `tbl_reservatie` WHERE op = '".$datum."' AND ruimte = 'vergader';"))) {
    // you table-rows to display data
}
```

Comment: With a while loop i get 2 tables with 1 appointment each but i want 1 table with 2 appointments how would i be able to do that ?

Comment: the `table` tags will should be out of the loop.

Comment: If i do that i get the same but in one table it loops over them again i get a table like this for example 8 9 10 11 12 8 9 10 11 12 ;)

Comment: What do you mean by that ?

Comment: can you print the data you are getting?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63859/discussion-between-maantje-and-sgt).

Answer (score 0):

if your code is getting data from URL like $_GET you need to give any rule before you do the query and is prefered to prepare "stmt" and after to do a cicle result array is not empty example:

```
  if(mysqli_num_rows($my_stmt_query)>0)
  {
      while($reult=mysqli_fetch_array($my_stmt_query))
      {
          echo '<tr><td ....';
          if($result['my_var']==$someData) { echo ' class="mystyle" ';}
          elseif($result['my_var']<$someData2) { echo ' class="mystyle2" ';}
          elseif($result['my_var']<$someData3) { echo ' class="mystyle3" ';}
          echo '>'.$result['my_row_data'].'</td></tr>';
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

there are two issues here:

1. data design: you need at least one attribute to differentiate the appointments on the same day. I guess the most fitting attribute would be something like appointment_start_time, or you define that each day has 4 slots of 2 hours each, starting at 8:00 am or something else along these lines
2. handling of the mysqli functions: as sgt wrote, you need a loop to get all rows of a result.
   `mysqli_fetch_assoc` fetches the row at the current cursor position in a resultset, *not* the whole resultset! Each call to mysqli_fetch_assoc moves the cursor one row further. When the cursor has reached the end (no more rows to fetch, or there weren't any rows at all in the result), `mysqli_fetch_assoc` returns false.

one common way to handle this would be along these lines:

```
 $result = mysqli_query($dbc,"SELECT * FROM `tbl_reservatie` WHERE op = '".$datum."' AND ruimte = 'vergader';");
 while ($datavergader = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    // do stuff with row data
 }
```

Comment: I tried it your way with a while loop but i get 2 separate tables but i want the same table with 2 appointments.